# Clustering of 1 dimensional data

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to learn the k-means clustering algorithm in MATLAB without using inbuilt k-means function. Say I have the data of size 1x100 and I want to group them into two clusters. So how can I do this. I want to visualize the two centroids and data together on a plot in MATLAB.
Note : When I plot in MATLAB, I am able to see only data but not the data and two centroids simultaneously.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Clustering in one dimension reduces to defining a threshold, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok. It means clustering effect will come in case of more than 1 dimension and for 1 dimension we will use the threshold .  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience in clustering, but yes, clustering makes sense when you have more than 1 dimension. For 1 dimension you want to split (cluster) the data in two intervals. See for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40475/28285)

Comment: Ok. Understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal K-means clustering algorithm in matlab could be:

```
p = rand(100,2); % rand(number_of_points,number_of_dimension)
c = p(1:3,:);    % We create 3 centroids

% We run this minimal KNN algorithm:
for ii = 1:10
    % Which centroids is the closest for each points ? min(Euclidian_distance):
    [~,idx] = min(sum((permute(p,[3,2,1])-c).^2,2),[],1);
    % We calculate the new centroids (the center of mass of the corresponding points)
    c = splitapply(@mean,p,idx(:))
end
```

And we can plot the result if needed:

```
hold on
scatter(p(:,1),p(:,2),[],idx(:))
scatter(c(:,1),c(:,2),[],'red')
```

And we obtain:

[image]

With our 3 centroids in red and the clusters with a distinct color.
Noticed that in this example the data are of dimension 2, but it will also work with any other dimension.

The 3 initial centroids correspond to 3 points of the dataset (randomly selected), it ensure that every centroids are the closest centroid for, at least, 1 point.

In this example there is 10 iterations. But it is certainly better to define a tolerance and stop the iteration when the centroids have converged.

Comment: Nice implementation. Didn't know about splitapply and I use Matlab for many years. However, the question starting with "I am trying to learn..." I wonder if it's best to just accomplish the task that the asker is trying to achieve. At least you did it in 2D, so the application to 1D is left as exercise. :)

Comment: Ok. will do it.